# Acceleration of the Moon due to the Earth's gravitational pull

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, gravity

If the Moon has an acceleration of 0.0027 m/s^2 with respect to the earth when in orbit, and it is stopped for an instant and then released, will the acceleration towards the earth now be different? If yes, will its acceleration towards the earth be constant or variable over time?

(I'm talking purely about Newtonian gravity and pre-relativistic physics, and ignoring the gravitational effects due to other heavenly bodies.)

Comment: *. . . it is stopped for an instant . . .* relative to what?

Comment: In this system, i'm considering only the moon and earth, so stopped for an instant relative to the earth

Comment: So the Moon (and Earth) will undergo free fall.

Comment: When you release the Moon are you returning it to its previous velocity? Or are you releasing it with zero velocity (relative to the Earth)?

Comment: How do you intend to instantly stop the Moon without shattering it?

Comment: BTW, the Moon's orbit has an eccentricity of ~0.0549. The Moon-Earth acceleration varies by  ~10% from its mean value. Here's a [daily acceleration plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ytaOM.png) for last year (in mm/s²), created using [JPL Horizons](https://ssd.jpl.nasa.gov/horizons/).

Answer (score 1):

If we presume a circular orbit for the moon, then the acceleration has a constant magnitude, from your question, of 0.0027 m/s^2, although the direction of the acceleration would be changing.

If the moon were stopped relative to the earth, then released, the initial magnitude of the acceleration would be the same as it depends on the distance from the earth $r$, from Newton's law of gravitation $$a=\frac{GM}{r^2}$$

where $M$ is the mass of the earth.  As time passed the moon would fall directly towards the earth, the acceleration would remain in the same direction but the magnitude would increase as the $r$ would decrease.

Answer (score 0):

The moon orbits Earth because of Centrifugal force balancing the gravitational force by Earth. And centrifugal force depends on the tangential velocity of the moon $$F_c = m\omega^2r = m\frac{v^2}{r} $$ where $m$ : mass of the moon
$\omega$ : angular velocity
$v$ : tangential velocity of moon
$r$ : radius of orbit of moon (assuming that its orbit is circular though it's not)
So if you decrease the tangential velocity of the moon then the centrifugal force will be decreased and the gravitational force will be greater which will result in the free fall of moon towards the earth. And yes it's acceleration will be variable over time.
Hope it helps. :)